# Undefined behavior or compiler bug? (std::sregex_token_iterator::operator++)

Tags: c++, linux, c++11, gcc, undefined-behavior

The following code produces different output on two systems, both of which are some kind of g++ 4.9.2 on Linux on Intel:

Ubuntu: gcc version 4.9.2 (Ubuntu 4.9.2-0ubuntu1~14.04); **Output: 2**

ArchLinux: gcc version 4.9.2 20150204 (prerelease) (GCC); **Output: 1**

Compile is with, e.g., *g++ -std=c++11 foo.cpp -o foo*. Changing optimization levels doesn't affect the results on either machine. Is there some kind of undefined behavior here that I don't see or is there a compiler/library bug somewhere?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <regex>

int main() {
  std::string string = "1 2 3";
  std::regex space_re("\\s+"); // whitespace
  std::sregex_token_iterator tokens(string.begin(), string.end(), space_re, -1);
  std::cout << ((tokens++)->str());
}
```

Comment: All compiler warnings switched on?

Comment: No warnings are produced with -Wall

Comment: `1` sounds correct, so I'm suspecting a bug that's been fixed since. Given the postfix ++, might be related to https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=64303

Comment: Ah, nice find, thanks. I agree that 1's correct, and the Ubuntu machine gives the wrong answer on the example in that bug as well while the Arch one doesn't.  So yea, looks like a recently-fixed libstdc++ bug..